# Why do Russian strings display wrongly for older programs on some Windows server machines?

Tags: windows, character-encoding, internationalization, clipboard

I have two Windows server 2016 machines with the Russian language pack installed. Our software on machine A displays some things wrongly (some activeX pages, some c++ programs), showing garbage instead of correct Russian strings. I've figured out that this is 'mojibake' - the text that is shown is a CP866-encoded string (with 00 added between each byte) wrongly displayed as a UTF-16LE string. I have another machine B that does not have this problem. I am at my wits' end trying to figure out the difference between these machines that could be causing this problem.

E.g. correct text:
Тревога и событие

Wrongly decoded string(mojibake):
Òðåâîãà è ñîáûòèå

(see screenshots below)

- The locale for non-unicode programs set to Russian (this is the 'classic' solution to this problem and seems to work for most people).
- Every language setting I can find is set identically for both machines.
- They have the exact same fonts installed.
- The HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Nls hives are identical for both machines, so same code pages for ANSI, OEM.
- Exact same version of our software installed.
- They have the same Visual C++ redistributables. They are both Windows 2016 but their updates are not exactly the same - I am working on this but am not too hopeful. I am told that we have this same problem on a Windows 2019 machine with a newer version of our software.
- The user that we are logging in as (Administrator) and other users have the same permissions and group policies.

[image]

The closest I've gotten so far is that I found that the clipboard contains slightly different things between the machines when I copy text from our software (a log viewing program). I used a program by NirSoft called InsideClipboard to check.
When I copy from either machine, this is what CF_TEXT contains:

[image: <>]

On the good machine, CF_UNICODETEXT contains correct UTF-16LE:

[image: <>]

22 04 40 04 35 04 32 04 3E 04 33 04 30 04 20 00
38 04 20 00 41 04 3E 04 31 04 4B 04 42 04 38 04
35 04 00 00

On the dodgy machine, CF_UNICODETEXT contains the same CP866 string with extra null bytes spliced in:

[image: <>]

D2 00 F0 00 E5 00 E2 00 EE 00 E3 00 E0 00 20 00
E8 00 20 00 F1 00 EE 00 E1 00 FB 00 F2 00 E8 00
E5 00 00 00

CF_OEMTEXT identical, not sure if relevant:
[image]

This is only when I copy text *from our program*. When I copy Russian text from notepad in the dodgy machine, CF_UNICODETEXT will contain the correct UTF-16LE string.

This sounds similar to my problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cyrillic-characters-appear-as-garbage-text-in-the/13373

We don't know exactly how the working (B) machine was set up, it is an old image and the people who set it up at the time have left. Is there a different way to install Windows 2016 that is more Russian and works with older programs?

Let me know if you need more information. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Please move this to superuser or wherever if appropriate.

Comment: Note: you didn't add any code in the question, and I think code may be relevant. "mojibake": this makes me thing there is some problem in your code. You should annotate at every read/write/open/change_encoding the expected encoding. Do not assume encodings just by reading it, check documentation (default may have changed). Do not assume your source code has the same encoding as the target computer (e.g. on string/char comparison), do not interpret any value on string if you do not know the real encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Giacomo. The code is VB6/Fortran/C for the programs we have found with this problem so far - I am doing my best to try to isolate the problem and come up with a repro that I can share. Note that these programs work totally fine on the other machine. The exes are binary identical, not compiled differently or anything. Maybe I need to get a debugger onto one to get the data you mentioned?

Comment: Same binaries of program, but Windows may get different encodings on different systems (different code page, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page, and so Cyrillic has incompatible code pages). I assume your program read text without specifying an encoding, and it uses the string as they were in an other encoding. Windows provide you also the default encoding, or if you know the original encoding, force it (use the explicit encoding parameter).

Comment: Yes I think your assumptions are correct. Thanks for the link, I read through everything again, and found that the dodgy system B behaves as though its default code page is 1252, not 1251. I think this because when I use Alt codes in notepad on machine A, I consistently get 1251 characters but I get 1252 characters on B. E.g. for win-1251 Д, it is 0xC4 which is alt+0196. I get Д on machine A but get Ä on machine B, which matches win-1252. So the problem seems to be that the machine's ANSI code page is behaving as though its 1252 even though it's set to 1251